# How to detect speakers from a dialogue?

Tags: nlp

I have a set of dialogues between a number of people. Each dialog is comprised of a number of utterances with corresponding speaker names. Now I get a new dialog that is segmented into utterances with unknown speakers (just marked as "speakerN") and the task is to guess the speakers from the set above. Is there a known name of such an NLP task and what are popular libraries or APIs that are used to achieve that?

**Note**: This is not NER, since the person is unlikely to be semantically extractable from the utterances, but rather to be guessed basing on usage of unique words and expressions, word stats, etc.